# How photorec works in recovering files?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, data-recovery

This is in relation to my previous question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/980452/recovering-files-when-windows-7-mbr-has-been-corrupted), but since it involves the program itself, I'm asking this separately for those who may use photorec.

I'm currently running photorec to recover files from the HDD with corrupt MBR. As I've never used it before, I've a few questions:

1. Never had a scan running this long. The drive's size is 750 GB, it's been scanning for 12 hours and only -30% is complete. The HD is warm and been running throughout this time. Is the extremely long process normal?
2. Do results appear during or after scan? Currently no files are appearing in the display. I'm running photorec on Windows 7, the interface is clean and simple but the window is a big white blank. I unchecked most the checkboxes, which means it should search only for file types I specified. It's been 12 hrs and close to 30% in, shouldn't stuff appear by now?
3. What will happen if the data recovered is more than the size of the drive I set to be recovered to? The size of the drive I'm recovering from is 750 GB and I'm recovering to a flashdrive of 64 GB. I believe the data I want to recover does not exceed 64 GB, but what happens if it does, will I have to re-scan to recover again?

I've checked online documentation for photorec but could not find satisfactory answers, maybe someone who is familiar with it can elaborate on the above.

Comment: 1) IIRC, yes. Its not a simple task. 
2) After. 
3) No idea. I try to have a big enough drive when I do this.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek okay. I must wait and find out then. Will the scanning damage or alter data on the HDD in any way?

Comment: Nope, Its entirely non destructive, assuming the drive itself is healthy.

Comment: 1) It sounds like the disk is generating I/O errors.  3)  the task will fail.  It is up to you to restore the files to a destination large enough to hold it.

Comment: @Ramhound hence me suggesting he image it first previously. He seems sure its virus related, so I worked off that.

Comment: there's a discussion for this here if you want to join me: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29827/discussion-on-question-by-xcare-recovering-files-when-windows-7-mbr-has-been-cor