# How to get MBR Wizard 3.0 to work?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, mbr, command-line-tool

I've downloaded the program files. Am trying to get [MBR Wizard's 3.0 CLI version](http://firesage.com/mbrwizard.php?x=4) to run from the command line and attempt fixing [my corrupt MBR issue](https://superuser.com/questions/980452/recovering-files-when-windows-7-mbr-has-been-corrupted). I'm running Windows 7 as admin, keep typing the commands like they say but all it keeps telling me in the command terminal is:

> mbrwiz.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

It's probably something silly I'm overlooking, but what am I doing wrong?

Do I have to put the files somewhere special? The site doesn't say any specifics in this regard.

How can I get this darn thing to work?!?

If anyone out there has used MBR Wizard or know how it operates, please leave me some tips or get in touch with me on the [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29827/discussion-on-question-by-xcare-recovering-files-when-windows-7-mbr-has-been-cor) about this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Try navigating to the install location using `CMD` and running it from there.

Comment: The also have a FAQ here with specific instructions on how to run it: http://firesage.com/mbrwizard.php?x=3

Comment: Sounds like it isn't in your `PATH`. Either add it there or naviagate as per MichaelFrank comment.

Comment: @MichaelFrank no, there's no specific instructions on running the program itself, link if you find it.

Comment: @DavidPostill whatever path I put, it's not working.

Comment: nvm, I found the problem why.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the matter was. I navigated to the file, tracing the path in the Terminal with each step and found a missing containing folder in the path. Once I added the containing folder in the path, it ran. Thanks for the tips everybody, Path was the right track, it's working now.

Comment: Good look with fixing your original problem ;)